# Difference between page edit option

Tags: master-page, edit

I have two pages in SharePoint 2013 that I have equal permissions on (Full Control), however one page has no 'EDIT' option in the upper-right of the page whereas the other has. Can anyone explain why this occurs? I've examined the HTML source for the page to see if I could find any differences and the only difference that I think could be of any importance is they seem to be using different versions of the 'Masterpage'. One is using

```
SEATTLE.MASTER:2.15.0.0.0.15.0.4701.1000.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-GB:RW
```

whereas the other is using

```
SEATTLE.MASTER:3.15.0.0.0.15.0.4701.1000.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-GB:RW
```

Or is this just a red herring?

[image: No Edit Option]

[image]

Comment: I know you said you went through html code but did you check if there is a script web part in the page where you don't see Edit option?

Comment: Just checked but there doesn't appear to be.

Comment: I think I may have found why. The page with the EDIT option is a page within the Site Pages library, whereas the other page isn't. Inspection of the URL shows the former ends /SitePages/Home.aspx whereas the latter ends /default.aspx. After a bit of reading, it appears that the home page of a site can be set to be a wiki page rather than the default page which is what seems to be the case here. Not sure how this happened though!

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found why. The page with the `EDIT option` is a page within the `Site Pages library`, whereas the other page isn't.

Inspection of the URL shows the former ends `/SitePages/Home.aspx` whereas the latter ends `/default.aspx`.

After a bit of reading, it appears that the home page of a site can be set to be a wiki page rather than the default page which is what seems to be the case here. Not sure how this happened, though!